# Is there a way to create fake directories and assign them a value via .htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess

The goal is to create a "fake" language subdirectory after the HTTP_HOST following up with the REQUEST_URI.

```
[Issue] 
localhost/public_html causes 404, but localhost/public_html/index works.
```

Current code:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /public_html/404.php
ErrorDocument 500 /public_html/500.php
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^$ /en/ [L,R=301]

# ASSIGN ENGLISH LANGUAGE PARAMETER IF NOT FOUND IN URL
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule !^(en|id|fr|ru|de|es|ro|tr|zh|ar)/ /en%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NC,R=302]

# ASSIGN LANGUAGE PARAMETER A VALUE IF FOUND IN URL
RewriteRule ^(en|id|fr|ru|de|es|ro|tr|zh|ar)/(.*) $2?language=$1 [QSA,NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^([^.]+?)/?$ $1.php [L,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule ^([^.]+?)/?$ $1.html [L,NC]
```

Folder directory:

```
xampp root folder
[
- public_html
]

website folder (public_html)
[
 - .htaccess
 - index.php
 - contact.php
 - style.css
 - etc.php
]
```

UPDATE:
Thanks to anubhava the problem has been successfully solved!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure these 2 rules are your **topmost** rules:

```sh
ErrorDocument 404 /public_html/404.php
ErrorDocument 500 /public_html/500.php
DirectoryIndex index.php

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteRule ^(index\.php)?$ /en/ [L,R=301]

# ASSIGN ENGLISH LANGUAGE PARAMETER IF NOT FOUND IN URL
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule !^(en|id|fr|ru|de|es|ro|tr|zh|ar)/ /en%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NC,R=302]

# ASSIGN LANGUAGE PARAMETER A VALUE IF FOUND IN URL
RewriteRule ^(en|id|fr|ru|de|es|ro|tr|zh|ar)/(.*) $2?language=$1 [QSA,NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^([^.]+?)/?$ $1.php [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule ^([^.]+?)/?$ $1.html [L]
```

Make sure to fully clean browse cache before testing this change.

Comment: Thanks for contributing and explaining why I shouldn't build a full url.
I tried the rules, prioritized them and cleared my web cache multiple times. 
Unfortunately /en/ doesn't get added to any url's and it doesn't assign it an value.

Comment: Exactly, that should be visible so people instantly notice that we are multilingual. The biggest issue is that I can't make it work for sub folders, e.g: www.test.com/product

Comment: I tried the updated rules and almost everything works, thanks! The only issue I have is that the index.php file causes a 404 error, other files seem to work. I updated the question with the current state of the issue.

Comment: I tested around and localhost/public_html/index works, the only issue that I have is that index doesn't automatically run when I call localhost/public_html

Comment: localhost/public_html works now, but it doesn't assign the /en/ to the url and a language value.

Comment: If I access localhost/public_html the url stays the same, but if I manually change the url to localhost/en/public_html it works. I have added the file directories to the question, is there maybe something wrong?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244181/discussion-between-anubhava-and-adelle).